# JS Sort an array into three occurrences

Tags: javascript, arrays, tabs

I need to arrange the array so that three are only instances left or less, for example

```
let tab = [ 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6, 6, 4, 6, 3, 7, 7, 3]
```

I would like to get something like this initially;

```
let newTab = [3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,7,7]
```

I am asking for help because I have no idea anymore.

Comment: Um... `tab.sort()`?

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? -> [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: So the array needs to be sorted, and every value can occur only a maximum of 3 times?

Comment: Sort the array, then iterate over the elements and push them into a new array if there are less then 3 of the current number in it.

Comment: Better wording of problem statement would be "I need to **modify** the array so that three are only instances left or less". Sorting could be an afterthought.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen, yes, I would like to get such an effect

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could group the data by thie value and take only the max length of three items for each group.

As result take the values in a flat array.

```js
const
    tab = [3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6, 6, 4, 6, 3, 7, 7, 3],
    result = Object
        .values(tab.reduce((r, v) => {
            r[v] ??= [];
            if (r[v].length < 3) r[v].push(v);
            return r;
        }, {}))
        .flat();

console.log(...result);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to an intermediate count object, and then [`flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) arrays of the correct size:

```js
const tab = [ 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6, 6, 4, 6, 3, 7, 7, 3];

const result = Object.entries(
  tab.reduce((a, v) => ({...a, [v]: (a[v] || 0) + 1}), {})
).flatMap(([v, count]) => new Array(Math.min(count, 3)).fill(+v));

console.log(result);
```

Sorting is achieved by virtue of integer object keys being numerically sorted by default.

Answer (score -3):

```js
let tab = [ 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6, 6, 4, 6, 3, 7, 7, 3]
let newTab = tab.sort()
console.log(newTab)
```

Comment: 1) If the question is really about sorting an array, it should be closed as a duplicate. 2) `sort()` modifies the array in place. No point in assigning to a new variable if you don't make a copy first.

Comment: I need to arrange the array so that three are only instances left or less